# MySQL Error 1054 In Where Clause

Tags: mysql, sql, database

The following SQL query has been giving me fits:

```
DELETE FROM zNMall1r.* WHERE zNMall1r.Phone = DoNotCall.Phone
```

When I attempt to execute, it returns Error 1054:

```
17:51:01    DELETE zNMall1r.* FROM zNMall1r WHERE zNMall1r.Phone = Phone.DoNotCall  
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'Phone.DoNotCall' in 'where clause'    0.078 sec
```

Anybody have thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is very clear it is saying that you have an unknown column (`DoNotCall.Phone`) in your `WHERE` clause.

Is this in another table and are you trying to `JOIN` on the table?

If so, then you will need to do the following:

```
DELETE z
FROM zNMall1r z
INNER JOIN DoNotcall o
   ON z.yourIdcol = o.yourIdCol
WHERE z.Phone = o.Phone
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't joined up a table named `DoNotcall`. MySQL will not search through all of its databases to try and find that column, so you get this error.

Comment: The DoNotCall table is definitely there. It works in other queries when it's not part of a WHERE clause. Hence my confusion.

Comment: Doesn't matter where you use `DoNotCall`. If it's not listed in a `FROM` or a `JOIN`, it's not present as far as the DBMS is concerned, and you'll get this error.